# Prove $\frac{\partial ln|X|}{\partial X_{ij}}=tr[X^{-1} \frac{\partial X}{\partial X_{ij}}]$ using adjoint.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, solution-verification

As part of proving this: [Prove $\frac{\partial \rm{ln}|X|}{\partial X} = 2X^{-1} - \rm{diag}(X^{-1})$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1493137/prove-frac-partial-rmlnx-partial-x-2x-1-rmdiagx-1)

Prove

$$\frac{\partial \ln \lvert X \rvert}{\partial X_{ij}}=\text{tr} \left[X^{-1} \frac{\partial X}{\partial X_{ij}} \right]$$ where $\forall \ p \ \in \ \mathbb{N}, \ X \ \in \ \mathbb{R}^{p \times p}, \ $ X is a positive definite matrix.

Condition: Use adjoint. For no adjoint: [Prove $\frac{\partial ln|X|}{\partial X_{ij}}=tr[X^{-1} \frac{\partial X}{\partial X_{ij}}]$ not using adjoint.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1493141/prove-frac-partial-lnx-partial-x-ij-trx-1-frac-partial-x-parti)

Note: just in case any of this notation seems wrong or or something, see [matrix cookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ehwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf): p.15's (141), p.9's (57) and p.8's (43)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I tried based on p. 304-306 of Harville:

Since $\frac{\partial |F|}{\partial x_{ij}} = tr[adj(F) \frac{\partial F}{\partial x_{ij}}]$ (apparently this is [Jacobi's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula)),

where adj(F) is the adjoint of F, the tranpose of the cofactor matrix of F and adj(F) = $|F|F^{-1}$,

we have:

$\frac{\partial ln|X|}{\partial X_{ij}}$

$=\frac{1}{|X|}\frac{\partial |X|}{\partial X_{ij}}$

$=\frac{1}{|X|} tr[adj(X) \frac{\partial X}{\partial x_{ij}}]$

$=\frac{1}{|X|} tr[|X|X^{-1} \frac{\partial X}{\partial x_{ij}}]$

$=\frac{1}{|X|} tr[|X|X^{-1} \frac{\partial X}{\partial x_{ij}}]$

$=\frac{|X|}{|X|} tr[X^{-1} \frac{\partial X}{\partial x_{ij}}]$

$=tr[X^{-1} \frac{\partial X}{\partial x_{ij}}]$

QED

Harville, David. "Matrix Differentiation." Matrix Algebra From a Statistician's Perspective. New York: Springer-Verlag, 1997. 285-332. Print.