# Prove $\frac{\partial ln|X|}{\partial X_{ij}}=tr[X^{-1} \frac{\partial X}{\partial X_{ij}}]$ not using adjoint.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, solution-verification

As part of proving this: [Prove $\frac{\partial \rm{ln}|X|}{\partial X} = 2X^{-1} - \rm{diag}(X^{-1})$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1493137/prove-frac-partial-rmlnx-partial-x-2x-1-rmdiagx-1)

Prove

$$\frac{\partial \ln \lvert X \rvert}{\partial X_{ij}}=\text{tr} \left[X^{-1} \frac{\partial X}{\partial X_{ij}} \right]$$ where $\forall \ p \ \in \ \mathbb{N}, \ X \ \in \ \mathbb{R}^{p \times p}, \ $ X is a positive definite matrix.

In words: derivative of logarithm of determinant of a matrix is trace of (inverse times derivative of matrix) and then each derivative is with respect to each entry of the matrix

Condition: Do not use adjoint. For adjoint: [Prove $\frac{\partial ln|X|}{\partial X_{ij}}=tr[X^{-1} \frac{\partial X}{\partial X_{ij}}]$ using adjoint.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1493139/prove-frac-partial-lnx-partial-x-ij-trx-1-frac-partial-x-parti)

Note: just in case any of this notation seems wrong or or something, see [matrix cookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ehwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf): p.15's (141), p.9's (57) and p.8's (43)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I tried based on Th2.14f in Rencher and Schaalje

Follow the proof (or directly apply) Theorem 2.14f by replacing $A = X$ and $x = x_{ij}$.
$$
\frac{\partial ln|X|}{\partial X_{ij}}
=
\frac{\partial ln|CDC'|}{\partial X_{ij}}
$$

Since positive definite matrices are symmetric, $X$ has a spectral decomposition: $X = CDC'$ where $C$ is an orthogonal matrix and $D$ is a diagonal matrix whose elements are the eigenvalues of X on the main diagonal and zero otherwise.

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial ln|CC'D|}{\partial X_{ij}}
=&\frac{\partial ln|D|}{\partial X_{ij}}\\
=&\frac{\partial ln(\prod_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_i)}{\partial X_{ij}}\\
=&\frac{\partial ln(\lambda_1\lambda_2...\lambda_n)}{\partial X_{ij}}\\
=&\frac{\partial (ln\lambda_1 + ln\lambda_2 + ... + ln\lambda_n)}{\partial X_{ij}}\\
=&\frac{\partial (\sum_{i=1}^{n} ln\lambda_i)}{\partial X_{ij}}\\
=&\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{\lambda_i}
\cdot 
\frac{ ( \partial \lambda_i)}{\partial X_{ij}}\\
=&tr(D^{-1} \frac{\partial D}{\partial X_{ij}})\\
\end{align}
where $D^{-1}$ is a diagonal matrix whose elements are the reciprocals of the corresponding elements in D on the main diagonal and zero otherwise.

$$
tr(D^{-1}) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{\lambda_i} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} D^{-1}_{ii}.
$$

$\frac{\partial D}{\partial X_{ij}}$ is a diagonal matrix whose elements are the partial derivatives of the corresponding elements in $D$ with respect to $X_{ij}$.

$$
tr(\frac{\partial D}{\partial X_{ij}}) 
= \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{ ( \partial \lambda_i)}{\partial X_{ij}}
= \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{\partial D}{\partial X_{ij}}_{ii}.
$$

and $\sum_{i=1}^{n} D^{-1}_{ii} \frac{\partial D}{\partial X_{ij}}_{ii} = tr(D^{-1} \frac{\partial D}{\partial X_{ij}}$) since the diagonal matrix $D^{-1} \frac{\partial D}{\partial X_{ij}}$ is the not only the matrix product but also the entrywise product of $D^{-1}$ and $\frac{\partial D}{\partial X_{ij}}$ since they are diagonal matrices.

It remains to prove that $tr(D^{-1} \frac{\partial D}{\partial X_{ij}}) = tr(X^{-1} \frac{\partial X}{\partial X_{ij}}).$
\begin{align}
tr(D^{-1} \frac{\partial D}{\partial X_{ij}})
&=
tr(D^{-1} \frac{\partial D}{\partial X_{ij}} + \frac{\partial CC'}{\partial X_{ij}})
\\
&=
tr(D^{-1} \frac{\partial D}{\partial X_{ij}} + C\frac{\partial C'}{\partial X_{ij}} + C'\frac{\partial C}{\partial X_{ij}})
\\
&=tr(CD^{-1} \frac{\partial D}{\partial X_{ij}}C' + C\frac{\partial C'}{\partial X_{ij}} + CD^{-1}C'\frac{\partial C}{\partial X_{ij}}DC')
\\
&=tr((CD^{-1}C')(C \frac{\partial D}{\partial X_{ij}}C' + CD\frac{\partial C'}{\partial X_{ij}} + CD^{-1}C'\frac{\partial C}{\partial X_{ij}}DC'))
\\
&=tr(CD^{-1}C' [\frac{C\partial (DC')}{\partial X_{ij}} + \frac{\partial C}{\partial X_{ij}}(DC')])\\
&=tr(CD^{-1}C' \frac{\partial (CDC')}{\partial X_{ij}})\\
&=tr(X^{-1} \frac{\partial X}{\partial X_{ij}})\\
&\hspace{10cm}{\it QED}\\
\end{align}

Rencher, Alvin, and G. Bruce Schaalje. "Matrix Algebra." Linear Models in Statistics. Second ed. New Jersey: John Wiley and Sons, Inc., 2008. 5-68. Print.

Answer (score 2):

Denote the eigenvalues of $X$ by $\{\lambda_k\}$. Then the eigenvalues of $F(X)$ are given by $\{F(\lambda_k)\}$.

Recall that **the** defining property of the exponential function is
$$\prod_k \exp(\lambda_k) = \exp\Bigg(\sum_k \lambda_k\Bigg)$$
or in terms of $X$
$$\det\Big(\exp(X)\Big)=\exp\Big({\rm tr}(X)\Big)$$
Setting $X=\log(Y)$ and taking the log of both sides yields
$$\log\Big(\det(Y)\Big)={\rm tr}\Big(\log(Y)\Big)$$
Next, consider the differential of the trace of a simple power function
$$\eqalign{
d\,{\rm tr}(X^3) &= {\rm tr}(X^2(dX)+X(dX)X+(dX)X^2)\cr
 &= {\rm tr}(\,3\,X^2\,dX\,) \cr
}$$
where the collection of like powers was made possible by the cyclic property of the trace.

Extending this to a generic function $f(X)$ yields
$$d\,{\rm tr}\big(\,f(X)\,\big) = {\rm tr}\big(\,f'(X)\,\,dX\,\big)$$
Combining this with the previous result yields
$$\eqalign{
 d\,\log\big(\det(X)\big) &= d\,{\rm tr}\big(\log(X)\big) \cr
   &= {\rm tr}\big(X^{-1}\,dX\big) \cr
}$$

Comment: Thanks Greg. How is my proof though? How do you know the fact about extension to generic function?

Comment: @BCLC The extension of the trace result to a generic function is really an appeal to Cayley-Hamilton,  Since any function which can be expressed as a Taylor series can be collapsed to a finite polynomial of degree $\le n$.  Differentiating the function is equivalent to differentiating the polynomial term-by-term.