# An identity involving the derivative of a scalar function with respect to a tensor-valued variable

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, partial-derivative, tensors

Let **B** be a tensor-valued variable, taking values from the set of second order tensors on the vector space naturally associated with Euclidean 3-space.

It is given that **B** is invertible.

I am looking for a proof of the following statement:

$$
\frac{\partial (\log \det \mathbf{B})}{\partial \mathbf{B}} =  \mathbf{B^{-T}}
$$

Also, it seems one would need an assumption on the positivity of the determinant of **B**, so I am guessing this is allowed too.

Thanks.

Comment: related? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1493137/prove-frac-partial-rmlnx-partial-x-2x-1-rmdiagx-1

Answer (score 0):

By the chain rule 
$$\frac{\partial (\log \det B)}{\partial B} = \frac{1}{\det B} \frac{\partial (\det B)}{\partial B} = \frac{1}{\det B} \det (B) B^{-T}$$

Apart from the last equality this should be clear, the last equality follows from Cramers rule. A reference is [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Derivative) and [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Cramer.27s_rule) on the same page.

(Note: it may be not completely clear what is exactly meant by $\frac{\partial}{\partial B} f(B) = A $. The interpreation of this expression is that $$\frac{\partial}{\partial B_{ij}} f(B) = A_{ij} $$ for every pair of indices $i,j$).

Comment: It was precisely the last bit that I was interested in. Anyway, the linked answer did the job for me.

Comment: related? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1493137/prove-frac-partial-rmlnx-partial-x-2x-1-rmdiagx-1