# Gradient of $\log(\det(AX))$

Tags: matrices, derivatives, determinant, vector-analysis, matrix-calculus

How to calculate the gradient with respect to $A$ of $\log(\det(AX))$?

Here, $X$ and $A$ are positive definite matrixes, and $\det$ is the determinant.

How to calculate this? Or, what is the result? Thanks!

Comment: $\log\det (A X)= \text{tr}(\log (A X))= \text{tr}(\log A+\log X)$

Comment: @polfosol relevant? [Prove $\frac{\partial \rm{ln}|X|}{\partial X} = 2X^{-1} - \rm{diag}(X^{-1})$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1493137). Here I say 'We first note that for the case where the elements of X are independent, a constructive proof involving cofactor expansion and adjoint matrices can be made to show that $\frac{\partial ln|X|}{\partial X} = X^{-T}$ (Harville). This is not always equal to $2X^{-1}-diag(X^{-1})$. The fact alone that X is positive definite is sufficient to conclude that X is symmetric and thus its elements are not independent.'

Answer (score 5):

Using $\frac{\partial}{\partial \pmb{A}} \text{log(det(}\pmb{A}\text{))} = \pmb{A}^{-T} $ and $\text{log(det(}\pmb{A}\pmb{X}\text{))} = \text{log(det(}\pmb{A}\text{)det(}\pmb{X}\text{)))} = \text{log(det(}\pmb{A}\text{))} + \text{log(det(}\pmb{X}\text{))}$, then $\frac{\partial}{\partial \pmb{A}} \text{log(det(}\pmb{A}\pmb{X}\text{))} = \pmb{A}^{-T} $

Comment: relevant? [Prove $\frac{\partial \rm{ln}|X|}{\partial X} = 2X^{-1} - \rm{diag}(X^{-1})$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1493137). Here I say 'We first note that for the case where the elements of X are independent, a constructive proof involving cofactor expansion and adjoint matrices can be made to show that $\frac{\partial ln|X|}{\partial X} = X^{-T}$ (Harville). This is not always equal to $2X^{-1}-diag(X^{-1})$. The fact alone that X is positive definite is sufficient to conclude that X is symmetric and thus its elements are not independent.'

Answer (score 3):

If $(A,X)$ were rectangular matrices, then assuming that $M=AX$ is non-singular, you could proceed this way
$$\eqalign{\cr
 f &= \log\det M \cr\cr
df &= d\log\det M \cr
   &= d\operatorname{tr}log M \cr
   &= M^{-T}:dM \cr
   &= M^{-T}:dA\,X \cr
   &= M^{-T}X^T:dA \cr
   &= (X^TA^T)^{-1}X^T:dA \cr\cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial A} &= (X^TA^T)^{-1}X^T \cr\cr
}$$

Comment: relevant? [Prove $\frac{\partial \rm{ln}|X|}{\partial X} = 2X^{-1} - \rm{diag}(X^{-1})$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1493137). Here I say 'We first note that for the case where the elements of X are independent, a constructive proof involving cofactor expansion and adjoint matrices can be made to show that $\frac{\partial ln|X|}{\partial X} = X^{-T}$ (Harville). This is not always equal to $2X^{-1}-diag(X^{-1})$. The fact alone that X is positive definite is sufficient to conclude that X is symmetric and thus its elements are not independent.'