# derivative of the determinant of the sum of two matrices

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, trace

From Eq. 51 of the [matrix cookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf) we know that

$\frac{\partial \log\det (AXB)}{\partial X} = (X^{-1})^\top$,

where $\det(X)$ is the determinant of $X$.

I was wondering what is the derivative of
$\frac{\partial \log\det (AXB + C)}{\partial X}$. Is it still  $ (X^{-1})^\top$?

Thanks!

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1493137 ?

Answer (score 4):

Define the matrix variable
$$\eqalign{
 Y &= AXB+C \cr
}$$
Write the function in terms of this new variable, then find its differential and gradient 
$$\eqalign{
 \phi &= \log\det Y \cr
d\phi &=  Y^{-T}:dY = Y^{-T}:A\,dX\,B = A^TY^{-T}B^T:dX \cr
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial X}
 &= A^TY^{-T}B^T = \Big(B(AXB+C)^{-1}A\Big)^T \cr
}$$
When $(C=0)$ and $(A,B)$ are invertible, this reduces to the result that you found in the cookbook.

In some of the steps above, a colon was used to denote the trace/Frobenius product, i.e. $$A:B = {\rm tr}(A^TB)$$

Comment: thanks @greg, your response is really helpful! I want to learn the basic knowledge of matrix calculus (e.g., the mathematical tools you used above) Do you have any textbook/tutorial/materials recommendation?

Comment: Related: math.stackexchange.com/questions/1493137 ?

Comment: @BCLC No, this question has no symmetry constraint.  I've posted several times on the annoying topic of symmetric/structured gradients. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4004617/change-from-differentiation-wrt-to-matrix-to-wrt-to-inverse-of-matrix-for-symmet/4006025#4006025) is my latest.